# Automate HTTPS Login

Tags: qt, post, authentication, https

I'm looking at a login page, and I need to create a POST message for it. Here is the login page source.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">$(document).ready(function(){});</script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#FFF; background-image:url(satellite.png);  background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:top center; max-width:100%;">
<div id="login" >
    <form id="auth_user_sys" name="auth_user_sys" action="index.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Authentication</legend>
            <table>
                <tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                <tr><td><label>* Username </label></td><td><input id="user_sys" name="user_sys" type="text"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td><label>* Password </label></td><td><input id="user_p_sys" name="user_p_sys" type="password"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input id="btlog" name="btlog" type="submit" value="Connection"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2"></td></tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried and failed so far (I'm using Qt):

```
QUrlQuery urlQuery;
urlQuery.addQueryItem("user_sys",   username);
urlQuery.addQueryItem("user_p_sys", password);
QString params = urlQuery.query();

QNetworkRequest request(url);

request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader, params.length());

pNetMgr->post(request, params.toLatin1());
```

I say it fails because the reply to the POST is the same as the reply to the original GET for that URL -- namely the source for the login page.

Comment: "failed" in which way? which server response do you get?

Comment: Good question!  It failed in that I get a reply back with the same HTML as I got with a simple GET.  It basically just sends me back to the login page again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  In the Authentication section there are 3 "input names", but I was only sending 2.  I added the "btlog" item (see below), and it came back with a set-cookie and a link to the page I needed to go to.

```
QUrlQuery urlQuery;
urlQuery.addQueryItem("btlog",      "Connection");
urlQuery.addQueryItem("user_sys",   username);
urlQuery.addQueryItem("user_p_sys", password);
QString params = urlQuery.query();

QNetworkRequest request(url);

request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader, params.length());

pNetMgr->post(request, params.toLatin1());
```

Comment: Nice, this would have been my next two guesses. Let me add two hints: 1. it's about "input names" not about "input ids". In your example they match but it is always the "name" attribute that is the key for the field. 2. You still do an unnecessary copy of your data. Change `pNetMgr->post(request, QByteArray(params.toLatin1()));` to `pNetMgr->post(request, params.toLatin1());`

Answer (score 1):

First, QUrlQuery takes care of encoding itself:

```
QString username = "aba";
QString password = "equals-sign:=amp:&nice";

QUrlQuery urlQuery;
urlQuery.addQueryItem("user_sys",   username);
urlQuery.addQueryItem("user_p_sys", password);
QString params = urlQuery.query();

qDebug() << params;
```

displays:

```
user_sys=aba&user_p_sys=equals-sign:%3Damp:%26nice
```

I am wondering what types `username` and `password` have in your code because toPercentEncoding() does only exist for QByteArray and QUrl. You need QStrings.

Secondly, `params.toLatin1()` already returns a QByteArray. It makes no sense to convert it into an unhandy C-style-pointer and from there back into a QByteArray. Go for

```
pNetMgr->post(request, params.toLatin1());
```

Thirdly, you are sending latin1 encoded data. Does you username or assword contain characters, that are not in the [latin1 alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout)?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers!  The username and password were indeed QByteArrays, I'll changed them to QStrings.  The password has an '@' in it, but that's it.  Any other ideas on what might be missing in the POST.  Those changes doesn't make it work...